# sieve of Eratosthenes generalization to Dedekind domains or even PID's

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, principal-ideal-domains, dedekind-domain, sieve-theory, integer-rings

I'm Interested in finding irreducibles in Dedekind domains, (and especially integer rings) in an efficient manner.
I've tried to look around a bit but found no papers on this (admittedly my paper searching skills need more work).
So I'll appreciate links to any generalizations of the sieve of Eratosthenes to other rings, even if its just to other PID's.

EDIT: should this be moved to mathoverflow (or is it too basic for there)?

Comment: In the number field case, because else there is no ordering, you can limit your search to rings of integers of totally real number fields, no?

Comment: I think finding a useful order would be part of the theory.
Maybe a main ordering with the norm, and then you'll just need a sub-order that has some meaning with divisibility, e.g. not simply dictionary order ;)

A naive approach (for rings of integers) would be to just do the normal sieve, calculate all numbers with a prime norm and check if they have divisors.
That might be practical for fields with small class groups but this sounds unsustainable for arbitrary integer rings.